# UICollectionView: header view programmatically

Tags: iphone, uicollectionview

This is the way i am working on header.

```
  //    viewDidLoad

  [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class]forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionReusableView class] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"header"];

UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout= [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];

self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 390, 300) collectionViewLayout:layout];
layout.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:230.0/255.0 green:230.0/255.0 blue:230.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class]
        forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
self.collectionView.delegate=self;
self.collectionView.dataSource=self;
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 15;

[layout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];

self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout;
self.collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
self.collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
[self.collectionView setBounces:YES];
self.collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"HorizontalPickerCell"];
[self.view addSubview:self.collectionView];

   - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {
  if (section == 0) {
    return CGSizeMake(0, kHeaderHeight);
  }
  return CGSizeMake(0, kHeaderHeight + kInterSectionMargin);
  }

  - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView
  {
NSLog(@"levels count:%d", [arrLevels count]);
return [arrLevels count];
  }

  - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
 NSLog(@"vals count:%d", [arrSeats count]);
 for(int i=0; i<[arrLevels count]; i++)
 {
    if(section == i)
    {
        int c;
        NSString *cnt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrTot objectAtIndex:i]];
        c = [cnt intValue];
        return c;
    }
 }
 return 1;
 }

 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

//cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_s.png"]];

if (cell.selected) {
    [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_s.png"]]; // highlight selection
 }
else
 {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yellow_seat.png"]]; // Default color
 }

return cell;
 }

 - (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
return UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 12, 10, 10);
 }

 - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:  (UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
CGSize retval =  CGSizeMake(22, 20);
return retval;
}

- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UICollectionReusableView *reusableview = nil;

if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {
    UICollectionReusableView *headerView = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:nil forIndexPath:indexPath];

        self.lblHeader = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 10, 100, 30)];
        self.lblHeader.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.lblHeader.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        self.lblHeader.text = @"Level 1";
        [self.collectionView addSubview:self.lblHeader];
}
return reusableview;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
printf("Selected View index=%d",indexPath.row);

itemPaths  = [self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];

UICollectionViewCell* cell=[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_s.png"]];
 }

 - (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
UICollectionViewCell* cell=[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yellow_seat.png"]];
 }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The error you're seeing is pretty clear. You're trying to dequeue a reusable view but the collection view doesn't know anything about the reuse identifier you're passing.

You need to call `registerClass:forSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier:` before `dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:` is called.  I typically call one of the register methods in `viewDidLoad` so all the setup is done and I can just call the dequeue method. If you're loading your custom header and footer views from nib you can use the `registerNib:forSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier:` method.

### Edit

I see you updated the code. You need to move these lines

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout= [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];

self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 390, 300) collectionViewLayout:layout];
```

above the lines where you're calling the register class methods. You cannot send messages to an object before you allocate and initialize it.

Comment: That thing is done already please check in question last line.

Comment: Yes, you're calling it in the last line. It needs to be called BEFORE you call dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath: registerClass:forSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier: shouldn't be called from this method anyway. Move it to viewDidLoad or wherever you're configuring the view

Comment: Also the error you posted references "Test Header View" which, I'm assuming is coming from the other answer? Make sure you're reuseIdentifier's are the same. That's how the collectionview knows what type of reusable view you're dequeing.

Comment: No, that's not the issue, that was my posting mistake. i edited the question.

Comment: As I said that error's very clear. You aren't registering the class before calling the dequeue method. Without seeing more of your code I can't tell you where the error is. I'm unable to duplicate your issue after copying and pasting the updated code from this question. You now have 3 answers and all 3 are correct given the information we have.

Comment: You are right, but the issue is that class is not getting registered, and i don't know why. I am updating my question, so that you can be more clear to the problem. You can also check the another link of my question.

Comment: have updated my code please check.

Answer (score 12):

If you are not displaying anything on the header then how could you expect header view to show you something on header part of UICollectionView.Try following code.This is working code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    arry=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"One",@"Two",@"Three",@"Four", nil];
    [_collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionReusableView class] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView"];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


    - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [arry count];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 20;
}

// The cell that is returned must be retrieved from a call to -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell==nil) {
        cell=[[UICollectionViewCell alloc] init];
    }

    UILabel *label = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:21];

    if (label==nil) {
      label=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 60)];
      label.tag = 21;
      [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
    } 

    label.text = [arry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"cell is %@",NSStringFromCGRect(cell.frame));
    return cell;
}


- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(60, 60);
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIEdgeInsets insets=UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);
    return insets;
}

- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([kind isEqualToString:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader]) {

        UICollectionReusableView *reusableview = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        if (reusableview==nil) {
            reusableview=[[UICollectionReusableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
        }

        UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
        label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Recipe Group #%i", indexPath.section + 1];
        [reusableview addSubview:label];
        return reusableview;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: have updated my code please check.

Comment: check my next answer @iPhoneProgrammatically

Comment: It will always add label to your reusableview header whenever you scroll.

Comment: First you don't need the whole reusableView == nil statement - it's never nil, that's the whole point of registering the reusable view class with the collectionView. Second you might get a view you've already used, which will already have a label, so make sure to remove all subviews from the reusable view there....like so: [reusableView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];

Comment: 'kind' is a string, so you should use [kind isEqualToString:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader] instead of ==. This is important especially when you declare own kind.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that you're leaking the UILabel allocated in  viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind.

Comment: scope of label in within this viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind, so @aeu can you tell me where and how UILabel is leaking.

Comment: @Vive u r right string should compare using string method. I have updated my answer.

Comment: When you add the label to the content view it gets retained by the content view.  You need to then call release on the original that you allocated - so just after the line with [cell.contentView addSubview:label] you need to have [label release].   

Please refer to the [Apple documentation on memory management](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH) for more information.

Comment: @aeu as release doesn't work in ARC , so I have done some modification. Now label will be added only once.

Answer (score 4):

why are you adding lblHeader to self.collectionView add to headerView.And return headerView.Replace your code with it

```
    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {
    UICollectionReusableView *headerView = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:nil forIndexPath:indexPath];

        self.lblHeader = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 10, 100, 30)];
        self.lblHeader.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.lblHeader.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        self.lblHeader.text = @"Level 1";

       // [self.collectionView addSubview:self.lblHeader];
          [headerView addSubview:self.lblHeader];

       return headerView;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Typically you put this register line in the viewDidLoad or some sort of initialize so that it is not called over and over again. But mainly you have some confusion.  You register a class for the header but you dequeue a class on the footer.  You should register a class for both and dequeue the right one for each.

Notice your register uses UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionReusableView class] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"header"];
```

Notice your dequeue uses UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter :

```
UICollectionReusableView *supplementaryView = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter withReuseIdentifier:@"header" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

hope that helps.

Comment: No, that's not the issue, that was my posting mistake. i edited the question.

Comment: What is your current error?  That was removed from the question.

Comment: Is it just not showing up?  You told it the width of the cell is 0 if I am not mistaken.

Comment: thanks you gave me the idea of frame.

Comment: I am getting issue with shuffling of selections when scrolling, can you help in that. here is link "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16662363/selecting-multiple-values-shuffle-when-scrolled-uicollectionview"

Comment: It was my case :)

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
    //ON top 
    static NSString *headerViewIdentifier = @"Test Header View";
    static NSString *footerViewIdentifier = @"Test Footer View";


    - (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        NSString *identifier = nil;

        if ([kind isEqualToString:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader]) {
            identifier = headerViewIdentifier;
        }
        else if ([kind isEqualToString:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter]) {
            identifier = footerViewIdentifier;
        }

        // TODO Setup view

        UICollectionReusableView *supplementaryView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter withReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        return supplementaryView;
    }
```

Comment: but you haven't registered the class, it is giving this error.