# How do I add a view at the top of a UICollectionView for supporting things like a search bar or filter in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uicollectionview

I'm trying to add filters at the very top of the collection view so customers can refine and filter results or even change the way results are displayed. I'd like to achieve the look of the image below.

[image]

Comment: You would use a supplementary header view you provide with the `collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:` datasource method.

This is a basic part of collection views and there is lots of info out there on how to use supplementary views.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602227/uicollectionview-header-view-programmatically

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### One option:

Use one view controller A that holds holds everything but the collection view. For the collection view. A uses a container view just to layout the space and, of course, host a nested collection view.

The collection view can have its own view controller B or it can use controller A as its data source and collection view delegate. Both would work.

### Next option:

If it really is on the top only, then you can supplementary views as for a header. But the header will scroll along with the content of the collection. It does not stay on top.

Option one would provide you with more flexibility on the layout but (or because) it cleraly separates the scrollable collection from fix layout parts of the view.

Comment: This worked, not the exact effect I was looking for but worked. I'll post another Q to cover my exact needs. Thanks.